# VueJS a component in a layout does not update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've followed this blog post: [Dynamic Vue.js Layout Components](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/dynamic-vue-layout-components/) to build some layouts using dynamic components.

I've now put a side nav bar into the layout to update the router views.
While the nav works, I'm having trouble to show the modified styles of the active link.
The component works as expected if I import it into the main page outside of the layout. I guess that's because here it gets remounted with each route change.
But in the layout, nothing changes. I assume that's because the layout doesn't rerender when the route changes. I've tried vm.$forceUpdate with no success, so I'm looking for the correct way to get a component to remount itself once it is clicked on (if that is indeed the source of the problem)

UPDATE: I've managed to show this in codesandbox to make it easier to understand: [codesandbox.io/s/mqwl3jlvx8](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqwl3jlvx8)

My code looks like this:
App.vue:

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <component :is="layout">
      <router-view :layout.sync="layout"/>
    </component>>
  </v-app>   
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      layout: 'div',
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

The LayoutFile:

```
<template>
  <div class="LayoutDefault">

        <div class="box">

            <div class="wrapper">
            <SideNav class="sidenav" />
            <slot class="main"/>
            </div>
        </div> 

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SideNav from '@/components/crmSideNav.vue'

export default {
  name: "LayoutDefault",
  components: { SideNav, }

};
</script>
```

The SideNav component then has a v-for for several NavItem components with data passed as props. 
In the NavItem component, I have the following methods:

```
goTo(){
            this.myIconColor = this.iconColor
            this.myTextColor = this.textColor
            this.$router.push({ path: this.path })
        }


    },
mounted(){

      if(this.$route.path === this.path) { 

          this.myIconColor = this.highlightColor
          this.myTextColor = this.highlightColor
          this.myBackgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'

        }
    }
```

Comment: tryed to wrap `keep-alive` on your dynamic component? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: I have no problem inside the dynamic component, but in the layout that wraps it. My Nav component in the layout does not fire the mounted function only once at the beginning, and not on every item that is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mounted not firing, I solved this by exchanging events between the parent and the NavItem children. As the children are in a v-for loop, I need to set and pass the index as well as a ref in order to fire the event correctly.
Now, on route change, the emitting link gets the active style and the other children set themselves to "neutral".

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rjrxmx498q)

SideNav parent now looks like this:

```
    <template>
<div class="main">

      <SideNavItem v-for="(link,index) in links" 
                  :key="link.id"
                  :path="link.path"
                  :text="link.text"
                  :index="index"
                 ref="setStyle"
                  @clicked="updateStyle"  />

</div>
</template>

<script>
import SideNavItem from "./SideNavItem.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    SideNavItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      links: [
        { id: 1, text: "GoTo Page1", path: "/" },
        { id: 2, text: "GoTo Page2", path: "/page2" },
        { id: 3, text: "GoTo Page3", path: "/page3" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateStyle( index) { 

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.links.length; i++) { 
           this.$refs.setStyle[i].changeStyle( index);
        }

      },
  }
};
</script>
```

And the child NavItem:

```
    <template>

  <div class="link1" @click="changePage" :style="{ backgroundColor: 
  setBackground, color:setColor }">
  {{ text }}
  </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    path: { type: String },
    text: { type: String },
    index: { type: Number},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myBackgroundColor: "",
      myColor: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    setBackground() {
      return this.myBackgroundColor;
    },
    setColor() {
      return this.myColor;
    }
  },
  methods: {
       changePage(){

            this.$emit('clicked',this.index)

            this.$router.push({ path: this.path })
        }, 
        changeStyle(index) {

            if (this.index === index) {
            this.myBackgroundColor = "blue";
            this.myColor = "white";
            }
            else  {
             this.myBackgroundColor = "";
            this.myColor = "";
            }

        },
  },

};
</script>
```